# faketime adjusting clock rate freezing graphical applications?

Tags: clock, real-time

I am trying to trick Chromium to think time passes faster than it really does.

One user suggested I use `libfaketime`. It works, almost.

Specifying time shift works fine:

```
faketime -f '+1y' chromium-browser
```

In this case Chromium thinks it's running 1 year in the future.

If I try to speed up the clock:

```
faketime -f '+0 x2' chromium-browser
```

Chromium's UI freezes in 1 second.

Other graphical apps do the same thing, like lxpanel. But console binaries seem to be just fine going a tenth of realtime:

```
faketime -f '+0 x0.1' sleep 1
```

The above command takes 10 seconds to execute.

Is there anything I can do to make graphical applications work in slo-mo or fast-forward using `libfaketime`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Temporarily change time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85336/temporarily-change-time)

Comment: `faketime`, mentioned in the answer above, supports varying the rate at which the fake time progresses.

Comment: Just to prevent an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) situation, why are you trying to speed up a countdown in Chromium? Additionally are you certain that Chromium is polling the system time, or is it using the web server's time?

Comment: @Thegs, good question. Yes I am certain the website is polling chromium for the time wall.

Comment: @StephenKitt `faketime` seems the way to go. Tried to run `faketime -f '+0 x2' chromium-browser`. Chromium opens and the omnibox cursor does flash twice as fast, but the UI freezes in about 2 seconds and the terminal has the error `GetVSyncParametersIfAvailable() failed for 19 times!`