# Any way to make system time go slower or faster?

Tags: linux, time, clock

I'd like to make my system clock go slower or faster on Linux.

On Windows, there's a handy freeware called "[Time Travel](https://www.serialporttool.com/GK/time-travel/)". To get an idea of what it does, just check this image, everything is self-explanatory:

[image]

So setting the speed to 0.9, makes a real minute be just 54 seconds on your PC, and you can easily sync the system time to real-time again with just a click.

I'd love some kind of software or tool for Linux that also does this or something that comes very close to it. Does anyone know of anything?

Thanks.

---

PS: The picture and link to windows software is just to ilustrate that some real easy GUI solution for windows exists, and I would like to come close to it on Linux system.

Answer (score 4):

**adjtimex** is the tool to calibrate Linux system Clock（no affect to the CPU frequency）， it can let System Clock go slower or faster，but only small adjustment.

short description in `man 8 adjtimex`:

```
-t val, --tick val
              Set the number of microseconds that should be added to the
              system time for each kernel tick interrupt.
-f newfreq, --frequency newfreq
              Set the system clock frequency offset to newfreq.  newfreq can
              be negative or positive, and gives a much finer adjustment 
              than the --tick switch.
-s adj, --singleshot adj
              Slew the system clock by adj usec. 
-o adj, --offset adj
              Add a time offset of adj usec.
```

if you want clock go more faster you can use script to set the Sys Clock on a regular basis like this：

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import time

clk_id = time.CLOCK_REALTIME

def run(cycle, speed):
    while True:
        t = time.clock_gettime(clk_id)
        time.clock_settime(clk_id, t + speed * cycle)
        time.sleep(cycle)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(0.01,24) # set time every 0.01 second, 24 times faster than normal
```

Be careful when you want it go slower. you should keep time smooth， you can make time slower increase or stop，but you should not set it earlier then it had reach.
that is to say you can't go back in time.

So don't use script to force Clock slower.

Comment: Hello! Please do not forget on the Shebang, some people could be confused about what language you used, also syntax is at least somewhat highlighted. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I’m not aware of a system-local tool which can do this on Linux. However, there is a program which will do this for a process, and its children (with [caveats](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/faketime/faketime.1.en.html#BUGS)), which is often sufficient, `faketime` — see [Temporarily change time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85336/86440) for details.

I remember using a controllable NTP server for system-wide tests sometime around fifteen years ago; if I can remember what it was I’ll add the information here.

Comment: quoting from the BUGS section of the faketime(1) manpage: "Due to limitations of the LD_PRELOAD mechanism, faketime will not  work
       with  suidroot  and  statically  linked programs.  While timestamps and
       time offsets will work for child processes, **speeding the  clock  up  or
       slowing  it down might not work for child processes spawned by the executed program as expected**; a new instance of libfaketime  is  used  for
       each  child process, which means that the libfaketime start time, which
       is used in speed adjustments, will also be  reinitialized."